# personal libraries C-like in Python

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I'm facing this little problem
I have created a function that simply reads a file and loads data into a dictionary
I have to use this function many times and in different scripts
In C i would have created a .h file and a .c file and simply inserted something like include "mylib.h" where I wanted to use that function
How can I do something like that in Python?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: oh perfect! I didn't know they were called modules and I was looking for personal libraries with poor results...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the function 'fn' in a module file 'mod.py'
Import the module wherever you want to use it with

```
import mod
...
mod.fn()
```

or

```
from mod import fn
...
fn()
```